# Excel Formula: Find duplicates and compare dates in other column

Tags: excel-formula

Can someone please advise on a formula which:

looks at column A where I have duplicates and then compares the dates in column B returning e.g. x next to the higher date like on the photo below:

[image]

x marks the date that is higher (in relation to the pairs of duplicates seen in col A).

My guess is we probably need an array formula?

Comment: One option is `MAXIFS`.

Comment: @BigBen sadly not available in my Excel version

Comment: Then use an array formula with `MAX(IF(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created de-duped version of the column A and applied following formula:

```
{=MAX(IF($F$1:$F$428=V1,$L$1:$L$428))}
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort with two levels. Primary A and secondary B.
Then paste below formula in C1.

```
=IF(A1=A2,"","x")
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. The date is not taken into account here.

Comment: After sorting, the newer date will be at the end so no need to consider.